# i want to read a data from a file in console with bufferreader and vector

Tags: java

i need to add/read data from a file using bufferwriter/bufferReader and vector but it return null (no data found),

```
public void addRecord(Scanner strInput) ...;
public void viewAllRecord()  throws IOException{
        try (
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("adherent_db.txt"))){
        String record;
         Vector<String> fileRead = new Vector<String>();
            while ((record = br.readLine()) != null) {
                fileRead.add(record);
            }
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();            
        }
    }
```

the file is not emty but 0 data display in console

Comment: You're adding to the fileRead Vector, but that Vector isn't returned anywhere.  BTW, don't use Vector, use ArrayList instead.

Comment: Another comment: As of Java 1.8, to read all the lines you can call `Files.readAllLines(new File("adherent_db.txt").toPath())` (import `java.nio.Files`). That returns a `List<String>` with the lines you're after.